# How to make a div that will not affect content

Tags: html

I'm trying to add content independent of current content using a div. So basically I have a sentence and a picture that I want to be all the way to the side of the website. But adding them makes the website change. I want it to be added without changing anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like `div { position: absolute; right: 0; }` might do the trick. Try this [position](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/) tutorial.

Comment: The post was deleted and the answer was excellent in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="float: right">
```

Someone answered with that but their post was deleted.